# Collecting VINs on one site

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to log in to this particular site (http://www.vinquery.com/login.aspx) and I am able to do with Selenium but I am unable to do by using `urllib` in Python (2.6).

I tried this way:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import lxml
from lxml import etree

url='http://www.vinquery.com/login.aspx'
values = {'User Name' : 'xxx', 'Password' : 'yyy'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

...but using this program I am not getting any error. Is this the correct way?

Another doubt I have is how I can "Enter a VIN" in the particular box.

Here I should give the VIN by using `urllib`, then I should press the go button. The main thing is I should not use Selenium however I don't know how to use `urllib`in Python.

Comment: The 'User Name' field has the name 'ctl00$SiteMaster$Login1$UserName' on that site (the password is also different).

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks I would recommend using [mechanise](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) instead of urllib.